# How to reuse promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I am trying to reuse the the data returned from promise here. But, the problem is, after the first call to `checkPromise` function, it immediately calls the second function, and the promise for the first function is not fulfilled, so it never returns any data, and hence it never enters the if clause. How do I reuse a promise?

```js
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var request = Promise.promisify(require("request"));


var url = 'http://www.google.com';
var obj = new Object;

function apiCall(url) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        request(url).spread(function(response, body) {
            return resolve(body);
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.error(err);
            return reject(err);
        });

    });
}

function checkPromise(url) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(url)) {   
        var rp = obj[url];
        //do something
    }
    else {
        apiCall(url).then(function(result) {            
            obj[url] = result; 
            //do something
        });
    }
}

checkPromise(url);
checkPromise(url);
```

Comment: Why don't you store the results in a closure?

Comment: A promise cannot be 'reused'. It is succeeds (once), or it fails (once), or has not done either. This is actually very good. Use a secondary mechanism to keep the data. In any case the promise looks to be used .. non asynchronously (ie. the promise has *not* completed yet on the second call), which is against the fundamental nature of a promise. (It is also generally bad to make a function "maybe async" as it [releases Zalgo](http://blog.izs.me/post/59142742143/designing-apis-for-asynchrony)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You likely have a timing issue.  Your `apiCall()` function is asynchronous.  That means it finishes sometime later.  As such, each time you call `checkPromise()`, all you're doing is starting a request and it finishes sometime later.  So, you call it the first time and it starts a request (that has not finished yet).  Then, your next call to `checkPromise()` gets called and it does it's `if` check before the first call has completed.  Thus, it finds nothing in the cache yet.

Your code is running two requests in parallel, not one after the other.

If you actually want to wait until the first request is done before executing the second one, then you will have to actually structure your code to do that.  You would need to make `checkPromise()` return a promise itself so code using it could known when it was actually done in order to execute something after it was done.

FYI, I don't see anything in your code that is actually related to reusing promises (which is something you cannot do because they are one-shot objects).

Here's one possible implementation:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var request = Promise.promisify(require("request"));

var url = 'http://www.google.com';
var obj = {};

function apiCall(url) {
    return request(url).spread(function(response, body) {
        return body;
    });
}

function checkPromise(url) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(url)) {   
        var rp = obj[url];
        //do something
        return Promise.resolve(rp);
    }
    else {
        return apiCall(url).then(function(result) {            
            obj[url] = result; 
            //do something
            return result;
        });
    }
}

checkPromise(url).then(function() {
    checkPromise(url);
});
```

Significant changes:

1. Return the promise returned by `request()` rather than create yet another one.
2. Change `checkPromise()` so it always returns a promise whether the value is found in the cache or not so calling code can always work consistently.
3. Sequence the two `checkPromise()` calls so the first can finish before the second is executed.

---

A very different approach would be to actually wait on the cache if a result you are interested in is already being loaded.  That could be done like this:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var request = Promise.promisify(require("request"));

var url = 'http://www.google.com';
var obj = {};

function apiCall(url) {
    return request(url).spread(function(response, body) {
        return body;
    });
}

function checkPromise(url) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(url)) {   
        // If it's a promise object in the cache, then loading 
        // If it's a value, then the value is already available
        // Either way, we wrap it in a promise and return that
        return Promise.resolve(obj[url]);
    } else {
        var p = apiCall(url).then(function(result) {
            obj[url] = result; 
            //do something
            return result;
        });
        obj[url] = p;
        return p;
    }
}

checkPromise(url).then(function(result) {
    // use result
});

checkPromise(url).then(function(result) {
    // use result
});
```

Comment: Added changed code example that not only allows sequencing of `checkPromise()` calls, but also removes several anti-patterns for more programming consistency and removing the creation of unnecessary promises.

Comment: The second example can be simplified. The promise return by API call should be a trusted Promise. If you call Promise.resolve with a trusted promise, it will just return the promise. This means that you can omit the `typeof` check and simply return `Promise.resolve(rp);`

Comment: @AdamvandenHoven - I implemented your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

few problems with your code, first in `apiCall`, you are doing a promise ant-pattern( no need for that new promise), second your checkPromise is doing a sync operation, so it must either return a promise or have a callback argument, so you code can be changed into:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var request = Promise.promisify(require("request"));


var url = 'http://www.google.com';
var obj = new Object;


function apiCall(url) {

    return request(url).spread(function(response, body) {
        return body;
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.error(err);
        throw err;
    });
}


function checkPromise(url) {
    var promise = Promise.resolve();
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(url)) {   
        var rp = obj[url];
        //do something
    }
    else {
        return apiCall(url).then(function(result) {            
            obj[url] = result; 
            //do something
        });
    }

    return promise;

}

checkPromise(url).then(function(){
    return checkPromise(url);
});
```

Comment: also like jfriend00 said, I am not sure how this as anything to with reusing promises.

Answer (score 0):

Given the way you are globally storing the result in `'obj[url]'`, it'd probably be easiest to do

```
function checkPromise(url) {
    if (!obj[url]) obj[url] = apiCall(url);

    obj[url].then(function(result) {
        //do something
    });
}
```

to basically make the request, if it hasn't already started, then attach a listener to the promise for when the result has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hos49kge/27/) is the simplest example of how to prevent multiple API calls if there are multiple similar request for something (cache check for example)

```
var _cache = {
    state: 0,
    result: undefined,
    getData: function(){
    log('state: ' + this.state);
    if(this.state === 0 ){ // not started
        this.state = 1; // pending
      this.promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        return (apiCall().then(data => { _cache.result = data; _cache.state = 2; resolve(_cache.result) }));
      })

      return this.promise;
    }
    else if(this.state === 1){ // pending
        return this.promise;
    }
    else if(this.state === 2){// resolved
        return Promise.resolve(this.result);
    }
  },
};
```

Simulating api call

```
function apiCall(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    log('in promise')

    setTimeout(() => {
        log('promise resolving')
        resolve(1);
    }, 1000);
  })
}
```

Making simultaneous requests.

```
_cache.getData().then(result => { log('first call outer: ' + result);
    _cache.getData().then(result => { log('first call inner: ' + result); });
});

_cache.getData().then(result => { log('second call outer: ' + result);
    _cache.getData().then(result => { log('second call inner: ' + result); });
});
```

Only one API call is maden. All others will wait for completion or use the resolved result if it already completed.