# Returning promises from Synchronous JS Functions

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying to understand promises in JavaScript.

For my example scenario, I want to write a method which either returns data from local "Cache" if available or makes an HTTP call to retrieve the data from server.  I always want to return a promise even when no asynchronous calls was made so that user of my JS function has a unified API.  How can I achieve that in Javascript.  I'm in ES 5.

Comment: I don't know which Promise library you're using (or if you're using the native JS ones), but they usually provide a method like [`Promise.resolve()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) which lets you create an immediately resolved promise. Sounds like the sort of thing you're looking for. Also, high-five for keeping your API consistent - functions with multiple return types are always a pain to work with.

Comment: Here's a means of using promises with a cache: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31421482/how-to-reuse-promises/31421769#31421769

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want them `Promise.resolve` function, which takes a value to be immediately resolved. Since you're on es5, you can either use a promise library like Bluebird, or you can use a transpiler like Babel to compile ES6 down to ES5.

Comment: Bluebird is awesome, but there is a lighter-weight library that is more a strict ES6 Promise -- https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise

Comment: Yeah I wasn't really endorsing one promise library over another, I was just mentioning it because it's one of the more popular ones. Personally I would go the Babel route, or if using node.js I'd use v.6.2 which is already promise compliant.

Answer (score 0):

First promises is ES-6/ecma2015 feature so you have to use something like babel  https://babeljs.io/ or even better you can use this pollyfill https://github.com/getify/native-promise-only.

```
var promise = getValue(); 
promise.then('do your stuff here '); 


function getValue(){
    return new Promise(function executor(resolve,error){ 
         getData(resolve);   // call your function that gets the data.
    }); 
}
```